# Linux install password lost and found

Tags: linux, unix

I just installed Linux on a virtual machine. During the installation, I setup account and password but later when I try to log in (after installation completes), I forget the password thinking I am having Alzhiemer [?]. really worried, someone could help me please ? Because now I can only log on with a guess account. Thank you so much.

Comment: May be http://www.alz.org/alzheimers_disease_treatments.asp... Just kidding!

Answer (score 1):

The usual procedure for this is to boot into single-user mode.  From there you can reset the password. The procedure for entering single-user mode will depend on which boot loader you use - GRUB or LILO.

For GRUB: Reboot the VM, highlight the line for Linux at the selection prompt, and press **e**.

For LILO:  Reboot the VM. At the LILO: prompt, type in **linux single** and press **Enter**. (You might still be prompted for a password - if so, try **linux init=/bin/bash** instead.)

You can also reset the password by booting from a cd, but that's a bit more involved.  I'd try the single-user mode route first.